# Arredondar valores de prestações para a primeira parcela

Tags: php, javascript

Por exemplo:

```
venda de R$ 200,00 em 3x:
parc 1: 66,67
parc 2: 66,67
parc 3: 66,67
```

Além de não facilitar o troco estaria cobrando um centavo a mais do cliente.

Precisaria de uma solução tal como:

```
parc 1: 68,00
parc 2: 66,00
parcl 3: 66,00
```

Para facilitar os trocos de vendas pelo crediário, como arrendondar o valor das casas decimais para primeira parcela , usando Javascript?

Comment: Basta dividires 200 por 3 que dá 66.67, retirares a parte decimal, fica então 66. E então somar a uma das parcelas o resto da divisão de 200 por 3.

Comment: Para isso eu uso uma logica similar a do @JorgeB. utilizando o método [allocate](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) da biblioteca [bigmoney.js](http://github.com/demchenkoe/bigmoney.js)

Comment: entendi a lógica @JorgeB tens como postar algum exemplo?

Comment: Vê a minha resposta.

Comment: ótimo @JorgeB. consegui aplicar perfeitamente no meu código, obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta dividires 200 por 3 que dá 66.67, retirares a parte decimal, fica então 66. E então somar a uma das parcelas o resto da divisão de 200 por 3.

Exemplo básico:

```
<?php
$value = 200;
$prest = 3;
$div   = (int) ($value / $prest);
$resto = $value % $prest;
$init  = $prest-1;
$fin   = $div+$resto;

echo "De {$value} tem de pagar {$init} prestações de {$div} e 1 prestação de {$fin}"; 
?>
```

[A funcionar no PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pf6a-7q5i)